# Handling multiple picture boxes more efficiently

Tags: c#

I have 12 picture boxes running like a slide show using a simple code of:

```
if (pictureBox1.Visible == true)
{
 pictureBox1.Visible = false;
 pictureBox2.Visible = true;
}
```

and repeat all the way till 12 then timer stop and im happy with this bit.

BUT im struggling to keep it pretty... Its really long for simple things.
for example when button1 is clicked :

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ // please teacher
    BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.please;
    button1.Visible = false;
    button4.Visible = false;
    timer2.Start();
    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.please;
    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.PleaseTeacher1;
    pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.pleaseTeacher_023;
    pictureBox4.Image = Properties.Resources;
    pictureBox4.Image = Properties.Resources;
    pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources;
    pictureBox6.Image = Properties.Resources;
    pictureBox7.Image = Properties.Resources;
    pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources;
    pictureBox9.Image = Properties.Resources;
    pictureBox10.Image = Properties.Resources;
    pictureBox11.Image = Properties.Resources;
    pictureBox12.Image = Properties.Resources;
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
    SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(slideshow_test.Properties.Resources.Please_Teacher_Opening);
    audio.Play();
}
```

The above code plays one slideshow before offering episodes etc.
then again for button2:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ // show2
        BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.show2;
        button1.Visible = false;
        button4.Visible = false;
        timer2.Start();
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources;
        pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources;
        pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources;
        pictureBox4.Image = Properties.Resources;
        pictureBox4.Image = Properties.Resources;
        pictureBox5.Image = Properties.Resources;
        pictureBox6.Image = Properties.Resources;
        pictureBox7.Image = Properties.Resources;
        pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources;
        pictureBox9.Image = Properties.Resources;
        pictureBox10.Image = Properties.Resources;
        pictureBox11.Image = Properties.Resources;
        pictureBox12.Image = Properties.Resources;
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(slideshow_test.Properties.Resources.Please_Teacher_Opening);
        audio.Play();
}
```

and this does the job i want it to do but is there a way to make this code easier to read for future ref (because I have 10 more shows to add) ?

Comment: And a Ugly question with a Ugly title.

Comment: you need to learn how to use arrays and loops...

Comment: You really want http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Shouldn't there be a resource name after `pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources;`? Like `pictureBox3.Image = Properties.Resources.picture03;`

Comment: @Rahul , yeah sorry about that it wouldnt let me put anything else like "how to make mulitple picturebox coding cleaner" it said words like coding wernt allowed

Comment: @MarcB thank you im going to check them out now

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yes but i decided to copy and past my code here getting rid of pic ref to save and confusion but in the program there are images inserted

Comment: @StillLearnin thank u for the link im new to all this myself so really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an array of images

```
private const int NumberOfImages = 12;
private Image[] _images = new Image[NumberOfImages];
```

Fill it with images when the form opens

```
_images[0] = Properties.Resources.myPicture_00;
_images[1] = Properties.Resources.myPicture_01;
_images[2] = Properties.Resources.myPicture_02;
_images[3] = Properties.Resources.myPicture_03;
...
```

Also declare an index to the current image

```
int _currentImageIndex;
```

In your timer tick event handler do something like this

```
if (_currentImageIndex < NumberOfImages) {
    pictureBox1.Image = _images[_currentImageIndex];
    _currentImageIndex++;
} else {
    // play sound or whatever you need to do here
    _currentImageIndex = 0;
}
```

Note that I am assigning the different images to a single picture box in turn, in order to create the animation effect, instead of having a lot of different picture boxes.

---

Here is a complete working example. Note that I have changed some details. There are always several ways of doing things:

```
public partial class frmAnimation : Form
{
    private Image[] _images;
    int _currentImageIndex;

    public frmAnimation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _images = new Image[] {
            Properties.Resources.st_anim_frame0,
            Properties.Resources.st_anim_frame1,
            Properties.Resources.st_anim_frame2,
            Properties.Resources.st_anim_frame3,
            Properties.Resources.st_anim_frame4
        };
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_currentImageIndex < _images.Length) {
            pictureBox1.Image = _images[_currentImageIndex];
            _currentImageIndex++;
        } else {
            _currentImageIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

You also must place a `Timer` component on the form and set its `Interval` to an appropriate number of milliseconds. Create the `timer1_Tick` event handler by double clicking on the timer icon. Note that I have added a `timer1.Start();` in the form's constructor in order to start the timer.

Of course you must have added image resources to your project. I got rid of the `const int NumberOfImages` and used an array initializer instead. That way, the array is automatically sized to the right length (`_images.Length`).

You asked about arrays and indexes. You can imagine an array as a piece of furniture having a number of drawers. You can access each drawer by specifying its index. The first drawer has the index 0 (`_images[0]`); the last, array-length minus 1 (`_images[_images.Length - 1]`). If an array has the length `N`, then the indexes are in the range `[0 ... N - 1]`.

[image]

Comment: hang on, im still very new to all this so let me understand what uve said.... u say using 1 picture box i then add a "const" event(? dont know what to call it) with the number of 12 images (which is correct.)

Comment: Then in that event" i insert all my images so would the code actual start "_images[0].image"  followed by my picture location or would the first part of that code be differnt somehow? i ve no idea about indexs so im going to read up on that. i can understand the "else" section but what does "if " do, does that change the pictures progressivly on timer tick?

Comment: i have just tried this method above, and i get no errors but doesnt work, i have tried placing these lines in any void (picturebox1clicl timer tick ect) shows no errors but wont show any pics, if i place it in the partial class ith the rest of the code below "Image[] _image..." it comes up as errors what am i missing? _images[0] = Properties.Resources.ancater_home_area;
            _images[1] = Properties.Resources.Another_Trap_by_Masaki1812;
            _images[2] = Properties.Resources.backgroundDefault_jpg;